# Leet code solving problem Palindrome Number

Tags: python

I have just started python, and while solving this leet code problem number 9.Palindrome Number, it's not working.
If I set variable x = 121, and run on the colab, it totally works, but when I copy and paste into leetcode and run it, the answer is incorrect. Only False statement is correct.

Please review my code

Code that I wrote on the colab

```
x = -101
x_string = str(x)
original = []
new = []
print(len(x_string))
for i in range(0,len(x_string)):
  original.append(x_string[i])
for i in reversed(original):
  new.append(i)
print(original == new)
```

Code that I wrote on the leet code

```
class Solution(object):
    def isPalindrome(self, x):
        x_string = str(x)
        original = []
        new = []
        for i in range(0,len(x_string)):
            original.append(x_string[i])
        for i in reversed(original):
            new.append(i)
        print(original == new)
```

Comment: As an aside: `l1 = list(str(x)); l2 = l1[::-1]; return l1 == l2`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an efficient solution to *Palindrome Number*

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, n: int) -> bool:
        if n < 0:
            return False

        reversed_num = 0
        x = n
        while x > 0:
            reversed_num = (reversed_num * 10) + (x%10)
            x //= 10

        return reversed_num == n
```

Store the initial number in a temporary variable, and reverse it. Then compare the results. Also, you can simply skip the negative numbers, instead of reversing them and comparing them.